# Combining multiple look around regex with a capturing group

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

Given a string like

`@1=a@2=b@3=c@4=d >> @1=a@2=b@3=c1@4=d`

I want to capture whats between @3 and @4 and then assert that in the second part of the string the value(c in this case) is NOT same.

To do this, I came up with

`@3=((?:\w|-|'|"|,|\.)+?)@4=d.+(?<=@3\=)(?!\1)(?=@4\=d)`

This captures `@3=((?:\w|-|'|"|,|\.)+?)@4=d` "c" but the next part(`(?<=@3\=)(?!\1)(?=@4\=d)`) of the regex does not work as intended. I hoped that `(?<=@3\=)` this will assert "@3=" `(?!\1)` will say assert `NOT first captured group` and `(?=@4\=d)` will assert @4=.

Any help in explaining why this does not work will be appreciated.

Comment: ur regex `@3=((?:\w|-|'|"|,|\.)+?)@4=d.+(?<=@3\=)(?!\1)(?=@4\=d)` is not matching anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesn't your pattern work? It contains 3 lookarounds on end at the end: `(?<=@3\=)(?!\1)(?=@4\=d)`. Lookarounds are zero-width assertions and are executed one after another with the regex index staying in the same place as before. That is, `(?<=@3\=)(?!\1)(?=@4\=d)` matches a place that is immediately preceded with `@3=` **and** immediately followed with `@4=` while `@4=` cannot start with the value in Group 1. It does not match the new value between the delimiters, and does not make much sense in the end.

You may use the following pattern:

```
@3=([\w'",.-]*)@4=d.*?>>.*?@3=(?!\1@)[\w'",.-]*@4=d
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g1izH5/2). When used against `@1=a@2=b@3=c@4=d >> @1=a@2=b@3=c1@4=d` string, the regex matches and captures `c` because it is not equal to the `c1` substring matched with the second `[\w'",.-]*`.

**Details**

- `@3=` - a `@3=` substring
- `([\w'",.-]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars that are letters, digits, `_`, `'`, `"`, `,`, `.` or `-`
- `@4=d` - a literal `@4=d` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `>>`  - a `>>` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `@3=` - a `@3=` substring
- `(?!\1@)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the text immediately to the right of the current location is equal to the text captured in Group 1 and is followed with `@`
- `[\w'",.-]*` - zero or more chars that are letters, digits, `_`, `'`, `"`, `,`, `.` or `-`
- `@4=d` - a literal `@4=d` substring

Comment: Note that `@` is enough in the `(?!\1@)`  lookahead because the expected chars the value consists of (`[\w'",.-]`) does not include the symbol. `(?!\1@4)` or `(?!\1@4=)` will do the same job here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `(?<=@3=)(\w++).+>>.+(?<=@3=)(?(1)(?!\1@4)\w++|\w++)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u2elwK/3)

Comment: he is asking explain why this does not help?

Comment: Thanks but I wanted it to NOT match

Comment: @mohit Sorry, I updated answer. Explanation is very simialir to previous one :) You can remove downvote :)